# Get key vault secrets list only once at a startup

Tags: java, azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

What I want to achieve is polling a list of key vault values only once at the start of a microservice. Instead my program polls a list of secrets every 30 mins.
This is my client configuration:

```
public void init() {
secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
        .vaultUrl(vaultAddress)
        .credential(new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .tenantId(tenantId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .build())
        .buildClient();
```

}

1.What refresh-interval should I use in application.yml in order to pull secrets list only once ?

2. Is it possible to get secretValue by secretName without polling the whole secrets list ?

Answer (score 0):

Responses to the 2 questions:

#1 How does the code snippet relate to the application.yml? You can call the SecretClient you create at any interval you like.

#2 Use getSecret(String name) on the SecretClient API